# Как создать API с аутентификацией(Laravel)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel, laravel5

У меня простая задача - сделать APi который возвращает json ответ с данными. Это я сделал с помощью Resource, который вызываю обычным  --resource контроллером в методе index. Данные приходят...
Роутинг у меня через api.php
Вопрос в том, как сюда добавить аутентификацию? Когда я захожу под пользователем то api его не видит. Я много рыл инет и уже потеряв надежду понять это - пишу к вам. Кто может помочь с этим?

После коментариев.... пробую сделать как в документации:

api.php:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController')->middleware('auth:api');
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Метод контроллера, где я вызываю Resource, который отправляет json-данные

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])->find($request->get('id'));
    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

Даже файл ресурса сюда кину:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->second_name,
        'postCount' => count($this->posts),
        'lastPostTitle' => $this->posts[0]->title,
        'lastPostImageSrc' => $this->posts[0]->getImage()

    ];

}
```

Вот и почему залогиненого пользователя с api_token редиректит во время запроса:
http://site/api/users?id=2
Как оно работает ??)))

Comment: почитайте про middleware

Comment: Так я пробовал брать auth и auth:api... но они всегда возвращают ноль... Я не понимаю вот этот момент

Comment: Ну, так-то и в офф [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication) этот момент неплохо описан

Comment: Пропустил как-то... Спасибо, очень ценная статья. Вот только не могу понять... когда мы сгенерировали токен при регистрации... как дальше проверять... Вот не доходит...

Comment: Нужно ли хешировать токены? Не понимаю суть работы... И это чертовски бесит...

Comment: покажите данные запроса, которые вы отправляете. Покажите headers запроса. Через что вы отправляете запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации подробно описано: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication

Добавляете в миграции таблицы users:

```
 $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
                            ->unique()
                            ->nullable()
                            ->default(null)
```

Далее рефрешите базу данных:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Создаете пользователя. Присваиваете вашему пользователю api_token, можете хэшировать, можете нет - без разницы, сложность и обновление токена - уровень логики вашего приложения. Для примера возьмем api_token=1111.

Смотрим дефолтный роут в api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Чтобы получить доступ к этому роуту нужно перейти по адресу:

```
domen/api/user?api_token=1111
```

Comment: А, так нужон каждый раз свой токен передавать??

Comment: Да, в этом и суть аутентификации по токену. При это не нужно быть аутентифицированным обычным методом, это никак не влияет

Comment: А как тогда узнать токен обычному пользователю? Ну сейчас то я могу вынуть из базы если он залогинен... А если гость? То как тогда?

Comment: Пользователь регистрируется на сайте, видит в админке свой токен для пользования api.

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам большое!